# PrintWriter different from regular printing

Tags: java, parsing, printwriter

```
String[] strarray = new String[dataLine.size()];
strarray = dataLine.toArray(strarray);
PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter("test.txt");    
for (int i=0; i<strarray.length; i++)
{
   pr.println(Arrays.toString(strarray));
}
pr.close();
```

when I look at test.txt for this, it outputs a set of data I do not want (specifically only a few of the last ones) in comparison to calling

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strarray));
```

any idea why this is happening and how to fix this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

let me give a more concrete example.

System.out.println outputs

```
[1040, 0, 6, 1, 11/12/2012, 3, 0, 0, 1, 12/27/2011, 0, 0]
[1041, 0, 6, 1, 11/13/2012, 3, 0, 0, 1, 12/28/2011, 0, 0]
```

while pr.println(Arrays.toString(strarray)) prints

```
[1041, 0, 6, 1, 11/13/2012, 3, 0, 0, 1, 12/28/2011, 0, 0]
[1041, 0, 6, 1, 11/13/2012, 3, 0, 0, 1, 12/28/2011, 0, 0]
```

and pr.println(strarray[i]); prints

```
1041
0
6
1
11/13/2012
3
0
0
1
12/28/2011
0
0
```

the desired output I want on my output file is the first one. However, the last two do not provide me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Being able to see the difference in the outputs may be beneficial.

Comment: The first one will output the complete Array as often as the array is long, the second one will output the complete array once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
pr.println(strarray[i]);
```

in your for-loop.

Unrelated to your question you should change this

```
String[] strarray = new String[dataLine.size()];
strarray = dataLine.toArray(strarray);
```

to

```
String[] strarray = dataLine.toArray(new String[0]);
```

because your way of doing it will first create an array of the desired size, and then change the reference to another array, wich will make your first array eligible for garbage collection. So don't create it, if you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks but that does not give me the output I want. Is there a way to write what Arrays.toString(strarray) displays?

Comment: `Arrays.toString(strarray)` will always have all the array elements. If you only want the first element, write `System.out.println(strarray[0]);`

Comment: what if I want all the array elements..I edited the original thread sorry!

Comment: as said before: '`Arrays.toString(strarray);` will always have all the array elements.' Make sure your array contents don't change in the mean time.

Comment: seems like I made a trivial error of reinitializing the list inside the for-loop therefore only getting the last iteration. I don't know why this took me so long. Thanks for the help.